# How to set the datepicker maxDate based on another datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have declared a date picker:

```
define(["ui/nal.ui.core"], function () {
    $.widget("nal.datePi", {
        options: {
            numberOfMonths: 2
        },
        _create: function () {
            var $el = this.element;
            $el.datepicker(this.options);
        }
    });
});
```

Which has 2 sons:

```
define(["ui/nal.ui.datePi","ui/nal.ui.textFieldDateDeparture"], function() {
    $.widget( "lan.datePiDeparture", $.lan.datePi, {
    });
});
define(["ui/nal.ui.datePi","ui/nal.ui.textFieldDateArrival"], function() {
    $.widget( "lan.datePiArrival", $.lan.datePI, {
    });
});
```

How can I set `maxDate` on `Arrival` to 1 year depending on `Departure.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something simpler like this work: (just pseudocode)

```
var depDate = $(".divToDate").datepicker('getDate');
depDate.setDate(depDate.getYear() + 1);

(".arrivalDiv").datepicker({
    maxdate: depDate;
```

basically you grab the date that is associated with your arrival date datepicker and add a year and set maxDate to that new value. You might have to getDate and then use the .addYear()